# Jquery sending a json with post

Tags: jquery, json

i have a flask server that take a json formatted as a string and return it (just for testing purposes) wich works when i send the request via curl like this:

```
curl  -X POST -d data='{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' http://localhost:5000/raw_query
```

but when i try with this simple jquery script:

```
    $.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/raw_query", '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}', function(data, textStatus) {
        if(textStatus == 'success')
        {
            console.log(data)
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(textStatus)
        }
    });
```

i get a 400 bad request error:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>
```

to add more detail: this is the flask code that executes the request:

```
@app.route('/raw_query', methods = ['POST'])
   def raw_query():
     data = json.loads(request.form['data'])
     return jsonify(data)
```

i really can't think of a possible reason for it, but then again i'm quite a rookie with jq so probably i'm missing something... any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try alter a bit your code as in the below example (have not tested this). Format your `data` ([A plain object or string that is sent to the server with the request](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#jQuery-post-url-data-success-dataType)) like:

```
 $.post("http://localhost:5000/raw_query", {data:JSON.stringify({username:"xyz",password:"xyz"})}, function(data, textStatus) {
        if(textStatus == 'success')
        {
            console.log(data)
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(textStatus)
        }
    });
```

Comment: @Barmar yes you are right, it has to be sent as json.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not sending the parameter name `data`. You're just sending the JSON string as the raw parameter, not the value of the `data` POST parameter.

```
$.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/raw_query", {
    data: '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}'
}, function(data, textStatus) {
if(textStatus == 'success')
    {
        console.log(data)
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(textStatus)
    }
});
```

Comment: i used json stringify, i wrote this way in the example just to make clear that the string is formatted in the same way. btw, same problem, 400 error is persistent.

Comment: I forgot `type: "POST"`, try it now.

Comment: Never mind, I didn't see the `data=` in the original `curl` command.

Comment: that actually work! would you care to explain why it works this way? on the jquery site non of the examples used a data formatted this way. looks like it has to take a key value pair ?

Comment: It is a key-value pair. The key is `data`, the value is the JSON string, just like in your `curl` command. You could also write `'data={"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}'`